# Python Exception Handling with in a loop

Tags: python, csv, error-handling, exception

An exception occurs when my program can't find the element its looking for, I want to log the event within the CSV, Display a message the error occurred and continue. I have successfully logged the event in the CSV and display the message, Then my program jumps out of the loop and stops. How can I instruct python to continue. Please check out my code.

```
sites = ['TCF00670','TCF00671','TCF00672','TCF00674','TCF00675','TCF00676','TCF00677']`

with open('list4.csv','wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    try:
        for s in sites:
            adrs = "http://turnpikeshoes.com/shop/" + str(s)
            driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
            driver.get(adrs)
            time.sleep(5)
            LongDsc = driver.find_element_by_class_name("productLongDescription").text
            print "Working.." + str(s)
            writer.writerows([[LongDsc]])
    except:
        writer.writerows(['Error'])
        print ("Error Logged..")
        pass

    driver.quit()
print "Complete."
```

Comment: Put the `try/except` inside the while loop, instead of the other way round.

Comment: just put the try..except inside the for loop

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just put the `try/except` block inside the loop. And there is no need in that `pass` statement at the end of the `except` block.

```
with open('list4.csv','wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for s in sites:
        try:
            adrs = "http://turnpikeshoes.com/shop/" + str(s)
            driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
            driver.get(adrs)
            time.sleep(5)
            LongDsc = driver.find_element_by_class_name("productLongDescription").text
            print "Working.." + str(s)
            writer.writerows([[LongDsc]])
        except:
            writer.writerows(['Error'])
            print ("Error Logged..")
```

**NOTE** It's generally a bad practice to use `except` without a particular exception class, e.g. you should do `except Exception:...`

Comment: Awesome!, It amazing how sensitive python is with indentation I had tried placing within the loop before and kept getting a syntax error. I will read up some more on exception handling and the use of an exception class.