# How can I find which object causes an error in for loop?

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, error-handling

```
my_list = ['list_obj_1', 'list_obj_2', 'list_obj_3']

for element in my_list:
    some_function()
```

This errors on a certain object, but I can't place which one. What is an easy way to find which object is erroring out on some_function()?

Comment: similar  query answered here   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38271394/python-exception-handling-with-in-a-loop

Answer (score 2):

A quick way to debug something simple like this would be with `pdb`. For example:

```
import pdb

my_list = ['list_obj_1', 'list_obj_2', 'list_obj_3']

for element in my_list:
    pdb.set_trace()
    some_function()
```

In this case you stop at each iteration, so you could try adding a `try-except`:

```
import pdb
my_list = ['list_obj_1', 'list_obj_2', 'list_obj_3']

for element in my_list:
    try:
        some_function()
    except:
        pdb.set_trace()
```

now when the error is thrown you will break and you can see which `element`. This way you will know which element is causing the issue without stopping at each iteration.

Link to docs for `pdb`:

https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/pdb.html